# How to pinch a hole into a UV Sphere?

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface, artifacts, boolean-modifier

I'm a Blender beginner and I'm trying to create a pumpkin creature for my game.

The problem is that I am using a UV Sphere to create the pumpkin and using a Boolean Modifier to make the eye and nose holes in my pumpkin, but the mesh is looking somewhat strange.

[image: The border has this "pinches" and I don't know how to solve that]

I'm using a Subdivision Modifier to try to solve this problem, but it still looks strange.

I tried to [make a new topology for this area, using a Plane with Subdivision and Shrinkwrap modifiers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ll5h76qzAlc). It looks better, but still strange:

[image: New mesh]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, boolean can create a bad topology, you can fix that, but the best is probably to create the hole from scratch (your second solution), or use a low-resolution object as boolean object, but maybe share your second object? Not sure why you think it doesn't work though...

Comment: Thank you guy, I've make some adjusts in the topology of the second solution and now its looking good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable [`LoopTools`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlSY8.gif) via menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Add-ons* → *LoopTools*:

[image]

Select a squarish grid on the *UV Sphere* and click <kbd>RMB</kbd> → *LoopTools* → *Circle*

[image]

- Press <kbd>I</kbd> to [`Inset`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html) faces and move mouse inwards
- Press <kbd>X</kbd> → *Delete Faces*
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to add [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) and scroll mouse forward. Click <kbd>LMB</kbd> or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- [`Select Edge Loop`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) of the hole with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill a face
- Enable [`Proportional Editing`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html) and select *Sphere* as [`Falloff`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html#falloff)
- Set [`Transform Orientation`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html) to *Normal*
- Select the center face and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad+</kbd> to increase the selection
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert selection and press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide faces
- Select center face and press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and move mouse to push face inwards along face *Normal*.
- Use mouse scroll wheel to adjust the size of the proportional editing influence
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all hidden geometry

[image]

Add *Subdivision Surface Modifier* for smoothness

[image]